# How to get access to the autocomplete combobox in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First, please forgive me my lamer's question, as I just start in web development.

I have an "input" element, in which a user is typing text.

At some point the page layout changes, triggered by logic, based on the element content. In result, the input element changed it's size and position, but the autocomplete combobox, associated with it, remains at the same position where it was before layout shift.

[image]

The same behaviour happens in different browsers.

My question is, how can I get access to the autocomplete combobox, in order to move it, refresh, or simply hide?

UPDATE: There is no anything special in the input element, no third-party controls, libraries, etc:

```
<input id="my-edit" type="text" placeholder="Input text here"/>
```

Comment: You will need to show us what the autocomplete combobox is. Is it the jQuery UI autocomplete? Show us the line that creates it.

Comment: That surely doesn't look like anything built into a browser ?

Comment: @Jon The autocomplete combobox is displayed by a browser. It's not a jQuery UI autocomplete. I thought maybe chrome/firefox had some API to operate with it, or there was a trick how to force the box follow the input element it's attached to.

Comment: @Jon: I assume this would be the browser default auto complete though it's not pretty clear

Comment: @Silver: Very interesting question I must admit

Comment: Try triggering a refocus when the layout changes, as in `$(document.activeElemet).trigger('blur').trigger('focus')`

Comment: Actually, that seems to be an issue, and there doesn't really seem to be much you can do about it -> http://jsfiddle.net/pC2pC/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the autocomplete by adding in `autocomplete="false"` like so:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="false">
```

Not sure about moving it though.